# reg add with %CD% and shortend path insted a the full stored in registry

Tags: windows

i have the following reg add command:

`REG ADD "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers" /V "%CD%\test.exe" /T REG_SZ /D RUNASADMIN /F`

this command is working and stored in the right place, but I have a problem with the path stored in the registry.

the test.exe file is in `d:\--=[testing]==--`

but the path which is stored in the registry looks as follows:

`D:\--__TE~1\Program\test.exe`

because of the shortened name, the reg add command is not applied to the test.exe.

is there any way to get the full path stored in the registry instead of the shortened? I tried all hints which I found, but no one worked. thanx in advance for the answers!

Comment: How are you calling that `reg add` command?

Comment: i have the command in a batch file.

Comment: I tested it inside a batch file yesterday and it worked for me ...